# Laravel query with max and group by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I need to create a select query in Laravel 5.1 which I will have no problems creating via regular SQL and I am wondering if you could help me to write it in Laravel.

I created this query that gets all Users that have a truck, trailer and delivery_date equals a particular date (comes from $week_array). It is working, but it is missing some components

```
$RS = $this->instance->user()
        ->with(['driver.delivery' => function($query) use ($week_array) {
           $query->where('delivery_date', [Carbon\Carbon::parse($week_array['date'])->toDateTimeString()]);
             }])
        ->with(['driver.trailer', 'driver.truck', 'driver.trailer.trailerType'])->get();
```

I need to exclude those drivers that have MAX delivery date which equals or greater than selected delivery date in the query above. This is the normal query that I need to plug-in to laravel.

In other words, I need to convert the following query (simplified) to Laravel:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    USERS
        INNER JOIN
    DRIVERS ON DRIVERS.user_id = USERS.id
        INNER JOIN
    DELIVERIES ON DELIVERIES.driver_id = DRIVERS.id
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND DELIVERIES.driver_id NOT IN (SELECT 
            driver_id
        FROM
            DELIVERIES
        GROUP BY driver_id
        HAVING MAX(delivery_date) >= '2016-05-10')
```

Comment: I'm affraid i didn't fully understood your question. Do you have problems with select the MAX values?

Comment: I added a simplified SQL that is working and which I am trying to convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `whereHas`. Try:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($week_array['date'])->toDateTimeString();

$RS = $this->instance->user()
    ->with(['driver.delivery' => function($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('delivery_date', [$date]);
    }])
    ->with(['driver.trailer', 'driver.truck', 'driver.trailer.trailerType'])
    ->whereHas('driver.delivery', function($query) use ($date) {
        return $query->where('delivery_date', '>', $date);
    }, '=', 0)
    ->get();
```

Also try validating the query looks right by replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()` and using the `dd` helper function.

Comment: Seems like you returning last_delivery date, I need to make sure that driver_id not in list of max(deliveries.delivery_date)>=$date

Comment: Also, getting this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'max(delivery_date)' in 'field list' `

Comment: Can you copy and paste the SQL that is generated?

Comment: I also changed my query a bit.